# in the top corner = at the top of?

Tags: word-usage

I have read the following sentence:

- You must write your name in the top corner of the envelope.

Is this sentence correct? I thought that an envelope had four corners: top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right. It seems to me that "at the top of the envelope" would make more sense here.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct, but it's ambiguous. There are two top corners of an envelope.

Typically you'd put your name at the top *left* corner of an envelope, at least in my country. I would guess the writer assumed the reader would know which corner.